# How to determine if transform is one-to-one?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

***Here is a image link to question...***

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neONt.png)

***Answer of this question :***

$T$ is not one-to-one.

***My question:***

Hello. I don't know how to determine if the transform is one-to-one. Most of them I could be able to solve by making them "equal to 0" form.

For this question, I made them $5x+10y+10z=0$, $-3x-6y-z=0$, $-x-y+z=0$, $-x-2y-9z=0$ and solve for $x=?$ $y=?$ $z=?$. Thus, I got $x=4z$, $y=-10z$, so I wrote down (4,-10,1) and also said it is not one-to-one function since it can vary based on "$x=4z$, $y=-10z$" relationship.

But it said I got wrong and also said this is not one-to-one function.
Thus, I simply don't know how to determine if the transform is one-to-one. So that I know when to make "equal to 0" process like above.

Thank you very much if you can help me! in easiest & simplest way

Comment: Can you use determinant. it's fastest.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam i thought determinant only works on square matrix..? the question is not square matrix

Answer (score 2):

Nullity is $0$ implies T is injective. Converse is also true